# mysql вычитание результатов запроса

Tags: mysql

выполняются 2 запроса

```
select * from table where a='aaaaa' and b='bbbbb'  
select * from table where a like 'aaaa%' and b like 'bbbb%'
```

нужно результат первого отнять из второго чтобы строки не повторялись во втором

Comment: не совсем понятно, что значит "строки не повторялись". но если именно отнять, т.е. вывести вторым запросом только строки подходяще по like кроме тех, что вывел бы первый запрос, то: `where a like 'aaaa%' and b like 'bbbb%' and NOT (a='aaaaa' and b='bbbbb')`

Comment: тяжко жить без `EXCEPT` :)

Comment: имею ввиду что запрос like должен содержать строки только с похожими значениями, а все точно совпадающие строки были бы только в первом запросе, вроде "строки не повторялись" вполне понятно звучит, зачем минусовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE a='aaaaa' and b='bbbbb'
SELECT * FROM table WHERE (a LIKE 'aaaa%' and b LIKE 'bbbb%') and NOT (a='aaaaa' and b='bbbbb')
```